# Общие вопросы!С++!

Tags: c++

Вопрос идеотскиий но я его повторю. Сам изучаю С++.Но пока есть много не допонимания как люди пишут более сложные программы чем сравнение чисел или вывод чисел от до 10(утрирую) читаю книжку Гербет Шилдт с++ базовый курс. Что делать после прочтения данной книги.где можно взять задачки для решения? Хочу работать в игровой индустрий на роли программиста с Unreal конкретно.но время идёт а
я старею и у меня нет четкого плана действия

Comment: задачки можно взять на ресурсах вида https://leetcode.com/

Comment: *"Что делать после прочтения данной книги"* **Во время** прочтения, после каждой темы пишите простенькую программу на эту тему, чтобы закрепить знания. *"где можно взять задачки для решения"* Не советую. Решение олимпиадных задач научит вас... решать олимпиадные задачи, и все. Если хотите делать игры на Unreal-е, то в эту сторону и копайте. Найдите в гугле какой-нибудь туториал по анрилу и вперед.

Comment: Скорее всего, ответы на этот вопрос будут основаны на мнениях, а не на фактах и цитатах. Необходимо переформулировать его так, чтобы на него можно было дать объективный ответ.

Answer (score 8):

ну вот например роадмап геймдева
[image: gamedev roadmap]